# What is the difference between these two array Iterations?

Tags: php, arrays, loops, object, iteration

I'm studying PHP for an advanced exam.  The practice test said that the first iteration is better than the second. I not figure out why.  They both iterate the contents of an array just fine.

// First one:

```
 foreach($array as $key => &$val) { /* ... */ }
```

// Second one:

```
foreach($array as $key => $val) { /* ... */ }
```

Comment: Yeah it tends to confuse people better: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6287970/php-foreach-statement-by-reference-unexpected-behaviour-when-reusing-iterator

Comment: I suggest you to read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10057671/how-foreach-actually-works).

Comment: What exam? I can't believe this was from ZCE

Comment: Related: [Fastest way to iterate array in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1596988/fastest-way-to-iterate-array-in-php)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> The practice test said that the first iteration is better than the second.

That isn't the best advice. They're different tools for different jobs.

The `&` means to treat the variable by reference as opposed to a copy.

When you have a variable reference, it is similar to a pointer in C. Accessing the variable lets you access the memory location of the original variable, allowing you to modify its value through a different identifier.

```
// Some variable.
$a = 42;

// A reference to $a.
// & operator returns a reference.
$ref = &$a;

// Assignment of $ref.
$ref = "fourty-two";

// $a itself has changed, through
// the reference $ref.
var_dump($a); // "fourty-two"
```

*Reference example on [CodePad](http://codepad.org/oRk3Nepa).*

The normal behaviour of `foreach` is to make a copy available to the associated block. This means you are free to reassign it, and it won't affect the array member (this won't be the case for variables which are always references, such as class instances).

*Copy example on [CodePad](http://codepad.org/Na5J7nL3).*

*Class instance example on [CodePad](http://codepad.org/CIksHsnK).*

Using a reference in a `foreach` has some side effects, such as a dangling `$val` reference to the last value iterated over, which can be modified later by accident and affect the array.

*Dangling reference example on [CodePad](http://codepad.org/i26usxSt).*

Comment: Thanks for the help!  Could you say a bit more about "reference as opposed to a copy"? My only understanding of & would be writing over a variable such as $Foo2 = &$Foo1;

Comment: I see. So if I use & I can edit the array outside the foreach loop by calling $val?  Thanks VERY much!  You did an amazing job at making this clear.

Comment: I still need a lot more practice/learning before I can take the PHP UNIT Test.  Do you have any suggestions on good websites to help me study?

Comment: @Willow That issue generally leads to more problems than usefulness. As for getting to know PHP, read a lot of Stack Overflow questions and ask when you get stuck, after you've given it the best you can.

Answer (score 1):

The first example includes the `&` reference-operator for `$val` --> any changes to `$val` will be saved to `$array`.

This is by no means "better" than example #2, though.